# Can I reduce 10 TextBox_Change() subs down to one?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, textbox

I have a text countdown label, which as I type in a textbox, it recalculates the remaining characters. At the moment I have a very messy 10 separate subs for 10 separate text boxes. Is there anyway I can reduce this to one sub that loops for any textbox 1 to 10? I have tried looping through where i is 1 to 10 but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Label1.Caption = 140 - (TextBox1.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Label2.Caption = 140 - (TextBox2.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    Label3.Caption = 140 - (TextBox3.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox4_Change()
    Label4.Caption = 140 - (TextBox4.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox5_Change()
    Label5.Caption = 140 - (TextBox5.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox6_Change()
    Label6.Caption = 140 - (TextBox6.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox7_Change()
    Label7.Caption = 140 - (TextBox7.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox8_Change()
    Label8.Caption = 140 - (TextBox8.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox9_Change()
    Label9.Caption = 140 - (TextBox9.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox10_Change()
    Label10.Caption = 140 - (TextBox10.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
End Sub
```

Had thought something like this might work, but it doesn't

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
For i = 1 To 10
    With Controls("Label" & i)
        .Caption 140 - ("TextBox" & i.TextLength) & " characters remaining"
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `.Caption = (140 - Controls("TextBox" & i).TextLength) & " characters remaining"`

Comment: You can add a class module and create an event for all textboxes. See the links above your question.